# RecyclerView adapter ViewHolder id is -1 sometimes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a Recyclerview to display list of images and other content. When the recyclerview is loaded and scrolled quickly then it is crashing.

When I debug I could see that

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
...
viewHolder.getItemId() // this returns -1, sometimes
```

I suspect that the Recyclerview Adapter views are not created fully, any suggestions for this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please show the rest of the adapter code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not shared the code, We are not sure whats your case but let me share a possible cases that might be your case.
Possible Cases for RecyclerView Crash:

```
1. This crash might be caused by the fact that the setViewHolder and onBind 
methods are being called while your list(used by the adapter) is being updated, but notifyDataSetChanged() hasn't been called.

2. This problem may caused when android start dealing with bitmaps. the main 
reason is lack of memory space and also, garbage collector cannot free some 
space.

3. If you using image , please confirm the image size because the size may 
cause this problem. Some case recyclerview was not able to hold the images 
with big resolution.

4. Double check if you are using all the data loading process in ( main/UI 
thread ), it my testing Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper().
```